# Trouble handling 302 redirect with jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Due to some requirement I need to login to a site using jquery ajax .. but when I try to do so .. the firebug console is saying that it is 302 error.
I have tried to implement the code for its handling but unfortunately with no success

Here is my code I have tried till now :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'>
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>


  $(document).ready(function(){


  $.ajax({

  url        : "https://testDomain/login.asp",
  async      : false,
  type       : 'POST',
  data       : {Username:'test',Password:'testPass'},
  success    : function(respText){alert(respText);},

  error      : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                  console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Location")); // undefined;
               },

  statusCode: {
               302: function() {
                               alert("page not found");
                             }
              },                
  complete  : function(response) {  
              if(response.status == 302) {  
                  window.alert('page not found');    
              }
   }
       })

  });

  </script>
```

when I see the response headers they show up as

```
Date            Wed, 13 Mar 2013 06:43:18 GMT
Location        https://testDomain/pageXXX.asp
Server          Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Set-Cookie      TravAuthV=e;path=/; domain=testDomain.com;
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

What am I missing .. ?? Or is there any other alternative to handle this

Thanks for your time .. any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything problem is in below line.

```
url        : "https://testDomain/login.asp",
```

you are sending SSL request using ajax and i don't think its working because it's violates Javascript's policy because it doesn't see the SSL Requested from the same source as the non-SSL url..

**What you can do?**

you can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://testDomain/login.asp
```

<kbd>[**Read More**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)</kbd>

Try using setting `crossDomain : true` and `dataType:jsonp` if not `jsonp` response then remove it.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'https://testDomain/login.asp',
    async      : false,
    type       : 'POST',
    data       : {Username:'test',Password:'testPass'},
    success    : function(respText){alert(respText);},
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',getToken());
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean I cannot send ajax request to ssl domain through non-ssl request... ?

Comment: @new_developer that was my mistake instead you need to pass authorization check function and create that function to check authentication.

Comment: I have created the function getToken() which is returing base 64 value of "test:testPass" .. but now ajax is not sending request .. :(

Comment: Any further suggestion on this ... ?